# Is there any downside in eating whole-grain rice instead of white rice?

Tags: nutrition

Health benefits of eating whole-grain rice are often mentioned. But is there any downside in eating whole-grain rice instead of white rice?

Answer (score 7):

There are some downsides to eating whole-grain rice, primarily that brown rice has [consistently higher levels of inorganic arsenic in it](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/es702212p) [including rice found in the U.S.](http://www.consumerreports.org/cro/magazine/2012/11/arsenic-in-your-food/index.htm). The EPA's maximum contaminant level for arsenic is [10 micrograms/L in water](http://www.epa.gov/teach/chem_summ/Arsenic_summary.pdf), and there's [some suggestion](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0269749108001759) that the level of arsenic contamination in brown rice could be pushing up against that threshold.

As far as I'm aware though, there haven't been any definitive studies on health outcomes for people consuming brown vs. white rice.

Answer (score 5):

#### Nutrients

A detailed analysis of nutrient content of rice suggests that the nutrition value of rice varies based on a number of factors (depends on the strain of rice and its color). Comparative nutrition studies on varieties of rice suggest that highly colored rice strains have more antioxidant properties<sup>[2009](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19138081)</sup>.

Red or black rice consumption was found (in mammals) to reduce the progression of atherosclerotic plaque development, however white rice consumption offered no similar benefits which can suggest may be due in in a lack of antioxidants found in other varieties of rice<sup>[2001](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11340093)</sup>.

In comparison to whole grain, the [white rice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_rice) is milled rice that has had its husk, bran, and germ removed.

For full comparison table of nutrient content, please check: [Comparison of rice to other major staple foods at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice#Comparison_of_rice_to_other_major_staple_foods).

#### Inorganic Arsenic in Rice

The downside of eating different type of rice can be amount of arsenic (naturally occurring element in air, soil, water and foods). It has been found that rice is susceptible to accumulation of arsenic from soil<sup>[Boston Globe](http://www.bostonglobe.com/lifestyle/health-wellness/2011/12/08/you-need-worry-about-arsenic-rice/KGsMAwBoe0NnYupiC68v9N/story.html)</sup>.

> Arsenic exposure during pregnancy is a public health concern due to potential health risks to the fetus<sup>[Medical Xpress](http://medicalxpress.com/news/2011-12-rice-source-arsenic-exposure.html)</sup>.

Summary table of Inorganic Arsenic in Rice and Rice Products:

[image: FDA - Inorganic Arsenic in Rice and Rice Products]

<sup>Source: [Inorganic Arsenic in Rice and Rice Products](http://www.fda.gov/downloads/Food/FoodborneIllnessContaminants/Metals/UCM352467.pdf) and [Full Analytical Results](http://www.fda.gov/Food/FoodborneIllnessContaminants/Metals/ucm319916.htm) at FDA</sup>

The FDA, the agency responsible for overseeing the safety of our food supply, has been monitoring arsenic content for more than 20 years, however not indicated that the average daily intake of arsenic is unsafe and not established standards the acceptable limit standards of arsenic in food.

<sup>Read more:</sup>

- [Arsenic poisoning: Food](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arsenic_poisoning#Food) & [Rice: Arsenic concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice#Arsenic_concerns) at Wikipedia
- [Rice as a source of arsenic exposure](http://medicalxpress.com/news/2011-12-rice-source-arsenic-exposure.html) at Medical Xpress
- [Surprisingly high concentrations of toxic arsenic species found in U.S. rice](http://www.speciation.net/News/Surprisingly-high-concentrations-of-toxic-arsenic-species-found-in-US-rice-;~/2005/08/03/1561.html) at Evisa
- [China: Inorganic Arsenic in Rice - An Underestimated Health Threat?](http://www.speciation.net/News/China-Inorganic-Arsenic-in-Rice--An-Underestimated-Health-Threat--;~/2010/05/19/5027.html) at Evisa
- [Arsenic Compounds](http://www.epa.gov/airtoxics/hlthef/arsenic.html) at EPA
- [EPA Computer Models Predict Exposures to Arsenic that Echo Reality (PDF)](http://www.epa.gov/ordntrnt/ORD/priorities/docs/Arsenic_in_Food_FS.pdf)
- ["Discussion Paper on Arsenic in Rice" (2011) (PDF)](ftp://ftp.fao.org/codex/meetings/cccf/cccf5/cf05_10e.pdf)
- Book: [Andrew A. Meharg and Fang-Jie Zhao, Arsenic & Rice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:BookSources/9789400729469)

Comment: Nice answer. Can't understand why data-table is so unprecise, particularly for brown rice, at least it seems unuseful

Comment: @santimirandarp, the arsenic content in rice depends on the arsenic content in the soil, which may vary greatly from location to location.

Comment: Yes @Jan, you might be right. But what I meant is, being what you say, the data is rather unmeaning, unuseful. Also we can check your hypothesis with some study from one place!